# Part-Time and Freelance working schedules: set, or on-demand

Tags: time, business-language

I'm trying to find a way to use fairly formal/professional language to describe two different models for work. I have a rough idea of the two models, but I am currently only able to use informal language and examples to differentiate them. What is more formal language that I could use to differentiate these two models? I'd like to find verbiage that is clear enough that I could ask a company "If I work for you, would the scheduling be X or Y?" and they would understand.

1. The first model is roughly what I would describe as "Uber-like" or "on-demand:" If I want to work, I can make myself available for working at anytime, for any length of time, and if there is demand for my work (a student that wants to do tutoring, a passenger to ride in my car, a gym-goer that needs my fitness coaching) then I do the work.
2. The second model is roughly what I would describe as "set" or "pre-scheduled:" It occurs in some type of pattern for X number of times. Maybe this is every day from 9:00 to 10:00 in the morning for two weeks. Maybe it is every week on Monday and Wednesday evenings at 6:00 to 7:00, repeating for 5 weeks. There is consistency in the schedule over time, and as the worker I have to commit to the schedule in advance.

Comment: ***Fixed** or **flexible** working hours?*

Comment: I've considered fixed and flexible, but I think the difficulty is that flexible can mean several different things. Companies use flexible to describe schedules that are fixed; schedules can be flexible in the sense that you can choose the hours you work and that it can be as many or as few as you like, but once you choose the hours they are locked in for 10 weeks and con't be changed until those 10 weeks are passed.